# is this client exasperation?

Tags: communication, email, clients

I've had to ask a client of ours who works as a government contractor what versions of software he requires. Every project at our company requires a TAP. A document outlining the software and versions of each needed.

Not having access to the share point where this TAP was stored, I figured it would be easier to ask the developer.

So this was my question to this developer:

> Hey Fred,
>
> Can you let me know the versions you need for alterix, tableau and tomcat? I was able to get the licenses for alterix and tableau from Ken.
>
> Also do you want anything else with Alterix? Like the Data, Designer or predictive tools along with server?
>
> Thanks,
>   Tim

And this was his response.

> Tim,
>
> Server License Key(s),Version Information and Specific tools are provided and documented by several team(s) and processes in company-TECH. Unfortunately, it appears that those are of not much use.  In any case, I am happy to do all over again.
>
> Alteryx – Latest stable version 10.X (Server/Designer. No need for data or predictive tools for this phase)
>
> Tableau – Latest stable version (10.x)
>
> Tomcat – Please select the latest stable version
>
> Thanks

I get the sense that my question was out of the ordinary and an annoyance to the developer. Was my question out of order, considering that I "should have read and understood the TAP and known" rather than ask him?

Comment: What's a TAP? And wouldn't it be better to get access to this seemingly critical resource?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The first part of the reply you got was rude, without any need for being rude. You asked a simple question, the guy had the simple answer to that simple question, so that was all he needed to write. If anybody found himself in the position of that person, they should realise that the rudeness will not help them in any way at all, at best it will be ignored, at worst they can make an enemy.

As far as you are concerned, the answer that you got was rude. You don't know what caused this rudeness, so it's best to ignore it. It is most likely that it had nothing to do with your question at all. And even if you *should* have figured out these version numbers, there was no need to be rude about it. And since he would know better than any documentation what versions he needs, he should be glad that you asked him and not consulted some documentation that might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Had you heard of K-TECH? Do you have access to it? If so, then you shouldn't have bothered Fred. But in any case, he explicitly says he is ok with telling you what you need, and at this point you should probably take him at his word. Thank him, and go learn more about K-TECH.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading too much into his reply. He says he's happy to start over, so no reason why you shouldn't get the latest stable versions and move forwards.

Anyone can make minor errors or need clarification, no need to dwell on it.